# Android exception - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException kotlin when I write to file

Tags: android, kotlin

I receive such error when my app crashes:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4096; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
```

My app crashes when I try to download photo from server. It points on this line:

```
do {
    val read = inputStream.read(buffer)
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read)//this line!!!!
}while (read!=-1)
```

maybe it happens because I converted while loop incorrectly from java. In java I had smth like that:

```
while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read)
}
```

I found [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-i-cant-apply-value-inside-while-loop/7762) recourse about my problem and created my own new `while` loop but as I see I did smth wrong. Why does it happen and how I can solve this problem?

### UPDATE

here is another way of solving my problem which was suggested:

```
while (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
   outputStream.write(buffer, 0, inputStream.read(buffer))
 }
```

it doesn't load photo to memory

Comment: The conversion is indeed different. The `while(cond){..}` form checks the termination condition *BEFORE* using `read` variable, and the `do{..}while(cond)` *AFTER* using `read` variable. So the error is using `read` when `read = -1` (and "Outside the bounds of the array"); trivially, `while (true) { val read = ..; if (read < 0) break; write(..); }` ought to 'work' and illustrate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the loop itself.

-1 is returned when there is no more data

`Do while {}` executes at least once, so if there is no data you will have this error.
`While {}` firstly checks the condition and then executes. In Java you used while, here in Kotlin you went with do while.

Comment: so how I can convert my java loop to kotlin, as I understood my loop is wrong?

Comment: `if (read != -1) { write }` will not loop , it will check only once. He may have to use while loop instead of do while.

Comment: @P.Juni, I have edited my question, my photo isn't downloaded anymore :(

Comment: try the loop while from the comment of your post -> `while (true) { val read = ..; if (read < 0) break; write(..); }`

Comment: can you add this variant from comment to your answer, because image isn't still loaded ? :(

Comment: i did smth like that -> `while (true) {
                val read = inputStream.read(buffer)
                if (read < 0) break;
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, inputStream.read(buffer))
            }` and it doesn't load my file to memory

Comment: thats it, basically if `read` will be -1 it will mean, that there is no more data. So if there is no data just don't write and leave the loop, otherwise you will have ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193615/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-p-juni).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what how exactly you are printing. Here is a way I am using in my app to write a text to a file.

```
  try {
          val sub = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/My Documents")
               if (!sub.exists())
                   sub.mkdirs()

               val txtFile = File(sub, "mTextFile.txt")
               val writer = FileWriter(txtFile)
               writer.append("My text")  //Append whatever text you want to write to a file.
               writer.flush()
               writer.close()

           } catch (e: FileSystemException) {
               e.printStackTrace()  //Handle exception properly
           }
     }
```